# How to set log metric name in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating a log metric with cloudformation using the following entry which works.

```
MetricFilter:
    Type: "AWS::Logs::MetricFilter"
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: "Services"
      FilterPattern: "ERROR There was an error"
      MetricTransformations:
        -
          MetricValue: "1"
          MetricNamespace: "AlarmTest"
          MetricName: "ErrorCount"
```

But I am not able to set  a name for the log metric itself, I can't find a property that will work. When you manually create it there is the option to set a filter name.

When I run this it works but the Filer Name is auto generated based on the stack name.

[image]